# Run test suite with gradle

Tags: android, testing, jenkins, gradle

I have a question about running `TestSuite`s with gradle.

So under `androidTest/java` I have two packages, the first one contains instrumentation tests (`ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`) and the other is a `TestSuite` which contains those instrumentation tests. If I run the test suite in Android Studio, it works fine. How can I run it from gradle? I mean, I would like to run it from Jenkins. What should be that gradle task? I have tried with `connectedAndroidTest`, and it runs the instrumentation test in non-specific order, instead of the test suite.

Answer (score 0):

You can add filters to choose your tests. If you only chose your test suite, you can use the normal test task provided by gradle.

```
test {
    filter {
        includeTestsMatching "*MyTestSuite"
    }
}
```